# check and remove an html tag that contains a certain text only

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web, cheerio

I have the following tags:

```
<script>//<script/>
<script>
 //

</script>
<script>//testing testing<script/>
```

how can i check and remove the script tag that has "//" only and not additional text or code.

Answer (score 1):

```
const element = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
const arr = [...element];
arr.forEach(el =>{
  if(el.innerHTML === '//'){
    el.parentElement.removeChild(el)
  }
})
```

i guess this should work

Comment: sorry I forgot to add a script tag with new lines which will make this not work

Comment: do you want to remove that tag too?
if yes just add `.trim()` in if check to innnerHTML